# dotnet run inside docker container does not update content

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core

I try to use asp net core with docker. 
I code on my local machine and I have mapped directory with my app to docker container I use. 
I do not build docker container whenever I want to run app, I just only exec dotnet build and dotnet run commands inside container.

The problem is, even files are updated in container before I build, and run app in container, the result is wrong. App runs but WITH THE CONTENT which was attached to container, when I build it for first time.

I have no idea why is that.

In my opinion if I set in Dockerfile workdir as e.g /dotnetapp and i mount dir with my app to /dotnetapp dir in container, all files in container should be overriden. And it happens. But when I build, and run aps, the content which app returs to me is old

Comment: It's definitely not enough information. Consider adding more details such as content of your `Dockerfile`, commands you run to build and publish app, command you run to build and run the container.